# Same content on wordpress site regardless page

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress website do not show any content else then the blog posts. If I go to another page the same content shows. In my dev environment (MAMP) it is not any problem.

Here the link to the site: [www.vivids.se](http://www.vivids.se/)

Comment: what you did let me know

Comment: You must post this question with more details under [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) section.

Comment: Check your template index file.

Comment: I have tried that. Other ideas what it can be?

Comment: I'm assuming you fixed this? Because I'm clicking around and everything sends me to a different page.

Comment: Yes, its working now. I think it was cache that tricked me.